# Inout functions vs functions that return the passed in parameter

Tags: ios, swift, pass-by-reference

In Swift, when is it preferable to use inout functions vs functions that modify a single parameter and return that modified parameter?

It's probably a case by case scenario and I feel myself that using a function that returns the passed parameter is more explicit in the call and therefore more readable, but I'm not sure on the memory impact of copying the object, for example.

Take the following example:

```
func addConstraints(to label: UILabel) -> UILabel {
  let constrainedLabel = label
  //Add all constraints to constrained label
   return constrainedLabel
}
```

Is this favourable to:

```
func addConstraints(to label: inout UILabel){
   //Add constraints
}
```

Thanks a lot and sorry if this has already been answered or it's too broad.

Edit because I apparently used the worst example possible:

What's better:

```
let num = 5
num = addOne(to: num)

func addOne(to num: Int) -> Int {
 return num + 1
}
```

or

```
let num = 5
addOne(to: num)

func addOne(to num: inout Int) -> Int {
  num + 1
}
```

Comment: In these examples, neither is needed. `UILabel` is a reference type.

Comment: In a more general context though, you should try to avoid using `inout` arguments and rather use pure functions without side effects as often as you can.

Comment: You cannot add 1 to `num`. It is a `let` constant.

Comment: Your second example won't even compile, since `inout` arguments cannot be declared as immutable and you also need to use the `&` sign when passing an `inout` argument to a function. Moreover, there's no return value in the function, so your function signature is also flawed. However, you shouldn't use that approach anyways, simply return the new, incremented value and store that in a new variable, don't use `inout` unless you absolutely need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost *never* need an `inout` parameter in ordinary Swift usage.

Certainly in the first case *you* give, you don't need an `inout` parameter *or* a return value, because a UILabel is a class, which is *reference type*.

In the second case, all other things being equal, the first approach is better:

```
var num = 5
num = addOne(to: num)
```

The `inout` example has exactly the same effect — it replaces the value of `num` with a different Int — with absolutely no gain, and an increase in danger.

Comment: To add: The only case when you really need to use `inout` it's when you're writing [`shorthand/compound assignment operator`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html)(like `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=` etc). And even then you doesn't really need to define them, because they always are syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

Use the first approach without having to duplicate the UILabel

```
func addConstraints(to label: UILabel){
  //Add all constraints to label
}
```

You can change the properties of an instance of class even if that instance is a constant (`let`).

Just like you can change the text of `let` label:

```
let label = UILabel()

label.text = "Hello"
print(label.text!)    //"Hello"

label.text = "world"

print(label.text!)    //"world"
```

There is already a function that does that in the Standard Library: [`addConstraints(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622513-addconstraints).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `inout` for reference type ( classes here `UILabel` ) only

```
func addConstraints(to label: UILabel) {

  // add constraints and they will be applied to the label
}
```